# Can I drop ES5 (differential) builds if I am dropping IE11?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

As the title suggests.

I have an Angular project which will no longer support IE11, does it mean that I can disable ES5 builds?

Comment: What advantage do you hope to get by disabling ES5 builds?

Comment: Build time improvements if nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave that on the builder build-angular. The builder is able to recognize by .browserlistrc if it is necessary generate differential builds

EDIT: I believe the angular builder uses [caniuse-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/caniuse-lite) or something similar to check if target browsers require a differential build. If you want, you can do it yourself by [can i use](https://caniuse.com/?search=es6)